# Self join inside table by multiple values. SQL, Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, self-join, sequel

Please help with self join inside one table by different fields. given table "Items":

Used PostgreSQL.

I need to get all the values from such table, for which `factId = 'fact:170'` and `factId1 ='fact:171'` and `factId1.value ='false'` and `arrayIndexes` are the same.

It means `factId` 170 & 171 have relation one-to one using the same `arrayIndex`.

So all the values of `factId 'fact:170'` are needed, for which there is related by same `arrayIndex` `factId 'fact:171'` which have value `'false'`.

Here is column Item in the table, it means for each Item we have own set of values 170 and 171.
Thank you.

I tryed this but I am not sure this works fine and fast:

```
SELECT l.value
FROM Items l
INNER JOIN Items p on p.item  = l.item
INNER JOIN Items c on c.item  = l.item
WHERE l.factid  = 'fact:170' AND c.factid = 'fact:170'  
AND p.factid  = 'fact:171' AND p.value='false' 
AND p.arrayindex = l.arrayindex
```

there are a lot of duplicates after work.
Please check my query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be:

```
with t as (
  select distinct arrayindex
  from items
  where factid = 'urn:drug:171' and value = 'false'
)
select * from items
where arrayindex in (select * from t)
  and (factid = 'urn:drug:170' or factid = 'urn:drug:171') -- optional condition;
```

**[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OvYGhFBe)**

Details:

1. `t` CTE query finds unique `arrayindex` values for all rows which fulfill the condition
    `where factid = 'urn:drug:171' and value = 'false'`;
2. Outer query finds all the rows with `factid = 'urn:drug:170'`. Result rows are filtered by the `arrayindex` values which we received from the previous step.

Comment: In first part here : select distinct arrayindex
  from items
  where factid = 'urn:drug:171' and value = 'false' you get all arrayindexes from table. This is error. because there can be arrayindex value for each different item. But the goal is to check for each particular item , that facts inside have realtion by arrayindex. So using other words, we have to check this but in relation to concrete item. arrayindexes are unique only for particular item (not for whole table)

Comment: @Heineken please give some concrete examples with corner cases. It isn't easy to follow your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your apparent problem are the duplicates in the source table.

The `170` row appears 3 times in your date, the `171` row two times.

To get a *one-to one relation* you must must somehow introduce a unique identification - I use the `row_number`.

Than it is a plain join with additional predicate on the *row number*

Query (with sample data as CTE)

```
with tab as (
select * from (values 
('urn:fact:drug:170', '88cafe', 15),
('urn:fact:drug:170', '88cafe', 15),
('urn:fact:drug:170', '88cafe', 15),
('urn:fact:drug:171', 'false', 15),
('urn:fact:drug:171', 'false', 15)
)
t (factId,value,arrayIndexes)
),
-- from here your query --
t170 as (
select tab.*,
row_number() over (order by value) as rn
from tab
where factId = 'urn:fact:drug:170'
),
t171 as (
select tab.*,
row_number() over (order by value) as rn
from tab
where factId = 'urn:fact:drug:171' and value ='false'
)
select 
 t170.factid, t170.value, t170.arrayIndexes,
 t171.factid factid2c
from t170
join t171 on t170.arrayIndexes = t171.arrayIndexes and
t170.rn = t171.rn;
```

Result

```
factid           |value |arrayindexes|factid2c         |
-----------------+------+------------+-----------------+
urn:fact:drug:170|88cafe|          15|urn:fact:drug:171|
urn:fact:drug:170|88cafe|          15|urn:fact:drug:171|
```

So you can join two rows, the third is skipped as there is no match on both sides

Comment: arayIndexes are unique only for particular Item, not for whole table. So we need to check arraindex=arrayindex for facts only in scope of specific Item value. It means for other Item we can have the same arrayindexes but they belongs to relations 170-171 inside this particular Item